# How can I prepare video for Azure Media Services myself (on-premises) in variable bitrate?

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I usually use Media Encoder Standard to encode 4k videos in H264 Multiple bitrate format. But it's just becoming expensive (for me) because of source 4k file size, so it take up to 20 hours when encoding in Azure.

So I wonder is there a way to prepare it myself for this format https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-mes-preset-h264-multiple-bitrate-4k ? I do video editing and color grading anyway.

Comment: Really? Two "-1" for what? Not programming question? But it's as important.

Comment: Hi,
It would help me to understand your scenario a bit more in detail, as the size of the source file and format as well as the encoding profile that you have chosen to output can seriously affect the encoding time.  Can you share more details about the source 4K file you upload (format, encoding settings, bitrate), and the encoding preset that you are using in MES?  That would help us to guide you better. 

You may be able to prepare a better source mezzanine or adjust your target encoding profile to get a better experience.

Comment: I shoot local concerts in 4k 60p (yes, I know) for my friends. I may go down to 4k 30p but not lower then that. Every concert is 1,5 - 2 hours and requires some editing so I do this in DaVinci Resolve. The output file is mp4 (4k 60p) and usually ~80-100 Gb (with 30p it will be probably ... what, 40%?). Then I upload it to Storage and create an asset in Azure (I have this implemented in my website) and share it on my own simple website (again, deployed to Azure). The most expensive part is encoding that into multiple bitrate format. So I wonder if I can do it my self with Resolve and package it

Comment: Got it.  I would definitely do an experiment of dropping it to 4K 30p and see if the experience is still good for the cost involved. I'm not sure there is a lot of value-add for 60p on concert footage, unless you have a ton of side-to-side motion (Guitar throwing!)  

On the encoding profile, what is the adaptive bitrate preset that you are using today? Are you creating your own custom one or using one of our default system presets?

Comment: Do you have a target cost per encode or hour that you are aiming for?  Also a target of performance? How fast of an encode?  Are you using S1,S2 or S3 encoding units to do the jobs?

Comment: You can keep the edited source in 4Kp60, and adjust the encoding preset to (a) use fewer layers, (b) drop to 30 fps. These changes, along with using an S3 Media Reserved Unit should improve speed and reduce cost. We can provide pointers to accomplish [a] and [b] if that'd work for you.

Comment: ok, I always use 'H264 Multiple Bitrate 4K', obviously with S3 encoding units. And I'm going to try to work with 30p next time and see how much cheaper it gets. Thanks for the hints!

Comment: (1) See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-custom-mes-presets-with-dotnet for information on how to customize your preset, (2) Take the JSON for the 4K preset from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-mes-preset-h264-multiple-bitrate-4k, and replace "FrameRate": "0/1" instances with "FrameRate": "30/1", (c) Lastly, drop some of the bitrates. Suggest using 1 4K layer, 1 1440p layer, 1 1080p layer, 1 720p layer, and 1 540p layer

Comment: Definitely take the time to get the JSON preset, and customize the heck out of it to reduce the costs! That will help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the answer to this, as can be seen in the comment thread above is to do several changes to your workflow to reduce the time and the costs:

1. Change your source content to be 4k 30p instead of 60p. There really is no need to have 60p for the type of content that you are filming. It's not really high action content.
2. This should cut your upload source data size in half...
3. Download the JSON for the 4K preset that you are using "H264 Multi Bitrate 4k" and customize it.  Don't trust that we have given you the right settings for your cost demands or scenario. :-)
4. Change the frame rates in the preset, drop some of the bitrate layers, remove some layers as Anil suggested above. This should seriously reduce the encoding time, and your overall output costs. Just cut it down to the bare minimum and give it another shot.

If that does not work out for you, ping us again at amshelp@microsoft.com and we can help figure out other scenarios to assist.

Thanks for using Azure Media Services! And also thanks for contributing to the community.

John D.